# Create groups and assign permission level using powershell and reading csv

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, spgroup

Some of my groups were deleted due to some mistake, wanna create a new group and apply permission level on these groups.
is there any way I can do these using PowerShell by reading a CSV file like

```
   groupName      permissions level  

   grp1           read 
   grp2           contribute 
   grp3           contributenodelete
```

---

```
      $groups = $site.RootWeb.sitegroups

      $COUNGRP= $groups.COUNT

      Write-Host $COUNGRP

      $mdate=  get-date -f yyyy/MM/dd-HHmm

      $csvfilename= "E:\PoCSolutions\spgroupsforcreation.csv"; 
      cls
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using PnPPowerShell to create groups and permissions.

Here is my CSV

```
GroupName,PermissionLevel
Test1,Read
Test2,Contribute
```

Here is snippet to create groups from the CSV

```
cls

$cred = Get-Credential -UserName "<<username>>" -Message "Enter password"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "<<site collection url>>" -Credentials $cred
$csvGroups = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\Groups.csv"

foreach($grp in $csvGroups) {
    Write-Host $grp.GroupName
    $newGroup = New-PnPGroup -Title $grp.GroupName
    $role = $grp.PermissionLevel

    Set-PnPGroup -AddRole -Title $newGroup.Title -Identity $newGroup.Id

}

Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Here are the reference articles for additional information

[How to create a SharePoint group](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/NewPnPGroup.md)

[How to update a group with permissions](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/SetPnPGroup.md)

Comment: I think this is meant for SPO, I am  on on-prem. So  whether MS has released the PnPPowerShell  for on-prem? anyway, thanks for the sample code , i will try to build from your code.

Comment: Yes. There is a different version for On-premises which you can download from here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/pnp-powershell-overview